# Use genfromtxt function and can't slice the data in python 3

Tags: python

Now, There is a dataset name called 'iris' which needed to load in my program. I use the following code to read. And the last column is label column.

```
data = np.genfromtxt(ChooseDataset('iris'), delimiter=',', dtype=None, names=    ('sepal length', 'sepal width', 'petal length', 'petal width', 'label'))
```

Then, it displays tuple style in the data. (And I want to ask how to change this tuple style into list style.)

```
[(5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2, b'Iris-setosa') (4.9, 3.0, 1.4, 0.2, b'Iris-setosa')
(4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2, b'Iris-setosa') ...,
(6.5, 3.0, 5.2, 2.0, b'Iris-virginica')
(6.2, 3.4, 5.4, 2.3, b'Iris-virginica')
(5.9, 3.0, 5.1, 1.8, b'Iris-virginica')]
```

But I want to manipulate these attribute without class.
So I type this code.

```
print(data[0][:1])
IndexError: invalid index
```

Which methods do I need to change? Does someone can give some suggestions to me?
Thank you. (I know pandas is convenient, but I only can use sci-py and numpy to achive this code)

Comment: This is not a data mining question. Programming questions should be made in stackoverflow.

Comment: Please pick an answer if the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

In numpy, you can use double indexing to slice a column:

```
X = data[:, :-1]
y = data[:, -1]
```

`X` are all columns except for the last (2D), `y` is only the last column (1D).

---

This is the equivalent to matlab's:

```
X = data(:, 1:end-1)
y = data(:, end-1)
```

Or in R, this would be:

```
X = data[, 1:ncol(data)-1]
y = data[, ncol(data)]
```

I am not sure I understood your question because this is very trivial stuff. You really need to know these language features if you want to do anything interesting.

---

If you want to convert your labels to integers, just use list comprehension:

```
labels = ['Iris-setosa', 'Iris-versicolor', 'Iris-virginica']
y = [labels.index(i) for i in y]
```

---

**EDIT:** @Emre said I might have misunderstood the question. Indeed, I thought the problem was slicing an already imported CSV, not importing the CSV file.

`numpy.genfromtxt` will replace your strings by `nans`. If all you want is to remove that columns, then that is good enough. But if you want to keep them, you will have to convert them to integers or some such. I suggest using [`numpy.loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html):

```
# get the iris dataset from UCI (change to urllib.urlretrieve if using python2)
import urllib
urllib.request.urlretrieve('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data', 'iris.data')

labels = [b'Iris-setosa', b'Iris-versicolor', b'Iris-virginica']
conv = lambda x: labels.index(x)
np.loadtxt('iris.data', delimiter=',', converters={4: conv})
```

If you want to import every column except the last, just use `np.loadtxt('iris.data', delimiter=',', usecols=range(4))`.

Comment: Try loading his data into numpy like you suggested and you'll see the problem.

Comment: @Emre, updated the answer!

Answer (score 0):

It's straightforward with pandas:

```
from pandas import DataFrame as DF
data = [(5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2, b'Iris-setosa'),
(4.9, 3.0, 1.4, 0.2, b'Iris-setosa'),
(4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2, b'Iris-setosa'),
(6.5, 3.0, 5.2, 2.0, b'Iris-virginica'),
(6.2, 3.4, 5.4, 2.3, b'Iris-virginica'),
(5.9, 3.0, 5.1, 1.8, b'Iris-virginica')]
DF(data, columns=('sepal length', 'sepal width', 'petal length', 'petal width', 'label')).drop('label', 1)

=>    sepal length  sepal width  petal length  petal width
0           5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2
1           4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2
2           4.7          3.2           1.3          0.2
3           6.5          3.0           5.2          2.0
4           6.2          3.4           5.4          2.3
5           5.9          3.0           5.1          1.8
```

With just numpy:

```
from numpy import array
array([row[:4] for row in data])

=> array([[ 5.1,  3.5,  1.4,  0.2],
       [ 4.9,  3. ,  1.4,  0.2],
       [ 4.7,  3.2,  1.3,  0.2],
       [ 6.5,  3. ,  5.2,  2. ],
       [ 6.2,  3.4,  5.4,  2.3],
       [ 5.9,  3. ,  5.1,  1.8]])
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my thought:

```
path = 'titanic_sub.csv'

file = np.recfromcsv(path)

print(file[:3])  # This will give you first 3 rows

print(file[:2][:3]) # This one will not work as expected 2-row2 and 3-columns 



file = np.genfromcsv(path, names=True, dtype=None, encoding='ascii')

# Setting "names=" arg equal to "True", the first row strings will be automatically applied as field names, we can slicing it using these names 

print(file[['PassengerId', 'Survived', 'Pclass', 'Sex', 'Age']][:8])
```

And, if you doing it this way, you can using indexing slicing to subseting what you:

```
file2 = np.genfromtxt(path, delimiter=',', dtype=None, encoding='ascii')

print(file2[:5, :9])
```

If you find it interesting, you can trying these on "np.recfromcsv()" function, its a little bit different.